# use cordova-android create,cause cordova-2.2.0.jar: No such file or directory

Tags: cordova

When I use create command with cordova-2.2.0 it cause the error:

> cordova-2.2.0/incubator-cordova-android/framework/cordova-2.2.0.jar: No such file or directory

Comment: Is that jar at the expected location? It sounds like you may have an incorrect or incomplete installation.

Comment: Yes ,I  use the cordova source code.so got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you have downloaded the Cordova src and extracted the cordova-android.zip file.  Instead, just download the Phonegap download and extract it and cd into the phonegap/lib/android/bin folder to execute create.

Answer (score 0):

sorry.i use the wrong tools.i must download phonegap 2.2.0. then run.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hmm,I don't have the sufficient reputation.